# Difficulties in choosing a correct test for the analysis of variance e then a multi comparison test

Tags: r, anova, bonferroni

I have these groups :

```
G1 = [130020 125557 134032 105581 104417] 
G2 = [28753 19693 15273 26101 16109 19378]
G3 = [29765 28753 11737 11324 11265]
G4 = [49711 43110]
G5 = [43110 32005]
```

Looking at these I think that some assumptions for the ANOVA test decay given that some of these are  skewed departing from normality. Which tests should I use to substitute ANOVA and the bonferroni correction for the multi comparison test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, a Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric test finds
highly significant differences among the five groups.

```
x1 = c(130020, 125557, 134032, 105581, 104417) 
x2 = c(28753, 19693, 15273, 26101, 16109, 19378)
x3 = c(29765, 28753, 11737, 11324, 11265)
x4 = c(49711, 43110)
x5 = c(43110, 32005)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
g = rep(1:5, c(5,6,5,2,2))

kruskal.test(x ~ g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 15.645, df = 4,
  p-value = 0.003535
```

Then *ad hoc,* you could make *some* comparisons between pairs of groups using 2-sample Wilcoxon rank-sum tests.
However, because of ties, not all comparisons are possible. Also, because some groups are so small, it is not possible for a nonparametric test to
find significant differences at the 5% level involving them.

The order of groups from smallest to largest means is
3, 2, 5, 4, 1.

```
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3); mean(x4); mean(x5)
[1] 119921.4
[1] 20884.5
[1] 18568.8
[1] 46410.5
[1] 37557.5

wilcox.test(x3,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.5830249
Warning message:
 In wilcox.test.default(x3, x2) : 
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
wilcox.test(x2,x5)$p.val
[1] 0.07142857
wilcox.test(x5,x4)$p.val
[1] 0.4142162
Warning message:
 In wilcox.test.default(x5, x4) : 
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
wilcox.test(x4,x1)$p.val
[1] 0.0952381
```

And so on. Requiring something like the 1% level to
avoid false discovery in *ad hoc* testing, I do find
a significant difference between Groups 1 and 2.
I will leave further exploration to you.

```
wilcox.test(x2,x1)$p.val
[1] 0.004329004
```

*Note:* It seems worthwhile investigating why there are two ties among 20 numbers expressed
to five and six supposedly significant digits.

```
length(x); length(unique(x))
[1] 20
[1] 18
```

*Addendum:* In your Question you seemed to have excluded ANOVA on account of non-normal data. But in your comment you wondered about using using ANOVA and *ad hoc* t tests.
Here is my check on normality of residuals. May not be normal, but
probably not too far off:

```
d1 = x1-mean(x1);  d2 = x2-mean(x2);  d3 = x3-mean(x3)
d4 = x4-mean(x4);  d5 = x5-mean(x5);  d = c(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
shapiro.test(d)$p.val
[1] 0.4271326
qqnorm(d);  qqline(d, col="red")
```

[image]

Assuming the 20 residuals are nearly normal, here are P-values from `oneway.test` and a few *ad hoc* significant and nearly significant Welch t tests.
(You can see the entire printouts by leaving off `$p.val`s.)

```
oneway.test(x~g)

    One-way analysis of means 
  (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 42.624, num df = 4.0000, denom df = 4.2006, 
  p-value = 0.001213
```

Notice `denom df` $\approx 4.$ Without Welch-Satterthwaite correction for
unequal variances denom DF would have been 15. So sample
variances must be far from all the same, and it's a good
thing to have used Welch ANOVA.

Here are P-values from a few *ad hoc* tests. This is not a complete list; there are ten altogether.

```
t.test(x3,x4)$p.val
[1] 0.005860666
t.test(x2,x4)$p.val
[1] 0.02279379
t.test(x5,x1)$p.val
[1] 0.000910784
t.test(x4,x1)$p.val
[1] 0.0001425338
```

Comment: Thank you. Anova is not suggested so?

Comment: There is nothing to stop your doing one-way ANOVA w/ 5 levels of the factor and different numbers of replications at various levels. // That might be appropriate if the _residuals_ are roughly normal. To get the residuals, start with group 1 and find $d_{1j} = X_{1j} = \bar X_1,$ for $j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.$ Similarly, for the other 4 gps. You'll get 20 residuals. See if Shapiro-Wilk fails to reject. // You should still look into reason for ties, but ANOVA won't give error msg's about ties. I'd use R's `oneway.test` which doesn't assume eq var's. Welch t tests _ad hoc._ // Tried it. Similar reslt.